# Pass information from one Angular Component to another

Tags: angular

(If this is a duplicate, please let me know. I've found similar threads but couldn't reach a solution with their answers).

I have a  component that calls for their child (modal #1) which in turn is able to call another modal (modal #2). Modal #1 is just a standard form. If one of it's fields lacks the option the user wants, they can trigger modal #2 to add it.

What I'm wondering is, how can I pass data from modal #2 to #1 so I can inform #1 that a new element was added, and that it should use it as default in it's respective form field?

Comment: https://therichpost.com/how-to-share-data-between-two-components-in-angular-7/

Comment: Use material-dialog . And gets return value of it. You can open dialog2 from dialog1.

Comment: Use `@Input` if you want to pass data from Parent to Child and `@Output` for Child to Parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you should use `@Input` and `@Output`

Sometimes if it's not possible, for example because of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` you can inject service to the both components and communicate through **Subject/BehaviourSubject** from rxjs.

**code in service**

```
public subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

**code in component 1**

```
private subs = [];

constructor(private _serviceName: SomeService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.push(this._serviceName.subject$.subscribe(data => {console.log(data);}));
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
}
```

**code in component 2**

```
constructor(private _serviceName: SomeService){
    this._serviceName.subject$.next(anyData); // send data
}
```

**Don't forget to unsubscribe OnDestroy from the Subject!**

> That's a custom way to do it by yourself. Mostly libraries have built in way to communicate with dynamically generated components as modals.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to exchange information between modal it's to use a service. 
You best solution I can show you is here : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Use the last method :)